# How to run Go migrations on heroku on release?

Tags: go, heroku, database-migration

I'm writing a webapp in Go which uses Postgres for data storage and deploy in on Heroku. How can I run migrations automatically?

I use Go 1.13, for dependency management I want to use Go Modules.

As a migration tool I tried this https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate.
Locally I just downloaded latest binary from github releases and run CLI utility `./migrate -database $DATABASE_URL -path migrations up`.

Heroku Procfile content

```
release: migrate -database $DATABASE_URL -path migrations up
web: bin/myawesomegoapp
```

Of course, when I launch `git push heroku master` I get an error, that "migrate" no such file or directory, release command failed and push rejected.

So, how can I set up project to install `migrate` command to be able to run it on heroku on every release?

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell Heroku to build it, and it's a bit of a pain. Here's how you make it happen using go modules.

First you have to tell go modules to include it even though it's not referenced in the source. This is discussed [here](https://github.com/go-modules-by-example/index/blob/master/010_tools/README.md). This is my tools package which lives in `tools.go` in the root of my project:

```
// +build tools

package tools

// See this https://github.com/go-modules-by-example/index/blob/master/010_tools/README.md

import (
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4"
    _ "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate"
)
```

I then vendored my dependencies.

```
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
```

Finally, you have to tell Heroku to build the binary for `migrate` which is [not documented very thoroughly](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go). For this you not only need to specify the path where migrate lives, you need to include a "." which tells heroku you also want to look for `main` packages in the working directory. This is because (I'm guessing) using that directive overrides their default package search behavior. This is what my modules file looks like:

```
module ...

// +heroku goVersion 1.14
// +heroku install -tags 'postgres' ./vendor/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate .

go 1.14

require (
...
```

Comment: I followed your example, but I am getting:

-----> Running: go install -v -tags heroku ./vendor/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate . 
stat /tmp/build_2038f68e/vendor/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate: directory not found.


I have vendor/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate folder with main.go inside